# ACF + Gutemberg + REST API

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress-gutenberg

I registered gutemberg blocks with ACF and we’re returning beautiful json with **“blockName”: “acf/content”** and other data.

Endpoint is registered this way:

```
add_action(
    'rest_api_init',
    function () {

        if ( ! function_exists( 'use_block_editor_for_post_type' ) ) {
            require ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/post.php';
        }

        // Surface all Gutenberg blocks in the WordPress REST API
        $post_types = get_post_types_by_support( [ 'editor' ] );
        foreach ( $post_types as $post_type ) {
            if ( use_block_editor_for_post_type( $post_type ) ) {
                register_rest_field(
                    $post_type,
                    'blocks',
                    [
                        'get_callback' => function ( array $post ) {
                            return parse_blocks( $post['content']['raw'] );
                        },
                    ]
                );
            }
        }
    }
);
```

based on tutorial: https://wpscholar.com/blog/add-gutenberg-blocks-to-wp-rest-api/

But I have problem with Image Field – unfortunately plugin is returning only image ID, for example:

```
“image”: 12.
```

We can hit the endpoint of specific post for example: **/wp-json/wp/v2/media?parent=23** to get all media images from specific page ID, but that causes extra responses.

Does it possible to return somehow display **Image URL in blockName attrs** or you have any ideas how to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change return format in ACF field settings from `Image ID` to `Image URL`.

[image: ACF image "Return Format" settings]

Or, if you add fields from code:

```php
"return_format" => "url",
```